# MySQL Regex in Where

Tags: mysql, sql

Search the products with '^wall$', '\swall\s', '^wall ' or ' wall$' in its name. But it should not have results like 'wallpaper' or 'wonderwall'

```
SELECT * 
FROM `products` 
WHERE (products.name REGEXP 'wall?[:space]')  
ORDER BY products.updated_at DESC
```

So far the above `obviously` doesn't work. What should be the correct way to do this.

Updated the spec for clearer explanation.

Comment: Your spec is inconsistent. E.g. `wallpaper` matches `products with "wall"`. Please can you be clearer about what you are trying to achieve? Are you attempting to match `Any string where "wall" appears as a single word`?

Comment: That's the problem that I am having. "wallpaper" should not be matched. It should be either nothing at the end or in front or just space in front or at the end.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM `products` 
WHERE (products.name REGEXP '[[:<:]]wall[[:>:]]')  
ORDER BY products.updated_at DESC
```

Comment: [[:<:]] and [[:>:]] are special metacharacters that match Start of word and End of word. There probably are also other special metacharacters that could have been used (like \b)

Answer (score 2):

<strike>use [TRIM(products.name) = 'wall'](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim) instead of a regex...</strike>

after question update, use mysql equivalent of `\bwall\b` regex (word boundaries):

```
'[[:<:]]word[[:>:]]'
```

Comment: product name can be "wall flower" for example. this condition is not true

Answer (score 2):

Can you try this `REGEXP '[[:<:]]wall[[:>:]]'`